# Count rows of data and display in view ASP.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, count, data-retrieval

All i'm trying to do is count how many bookings have requested wheelchair access not sure with the best way....

```
using (var context = new TalyllynContext()) 
        {
            var count = context.Bookings.SqlQuery(" SELECT * FROM dbo.Booking Where Wheelchair_Access = 'true' ").Count();
        }
        ViewBag.Count = count;
```

This is what i want to happen in the SQL, but not sure how to make the view bag Count display the variable or is there a much better solution

In the view it can be anything as long as it shows the count value !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var context = new TalyllynContext()) 
    {
        ViewBag.Count = context.Bookings.SqlQuery(" SELECT * FROM dbo.Booking Where Wheelchair_Access = 'true' ").Count();
    }

return View()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using razor do something like this.

```
<p>@ViewBag.Count</p>
```

That will display the value in the view if you use the code you showed.

Comment: I Have an error in the controller... where count variable doesnt exist in current context

Comment: ViewBag.Count = "count"     Error is underlined in the quotes

Comment: So "count" is in the context of your using statement. Essentially you can only use the variable "count" inside the using scope. Try replacing "var count" with ViewBag.Count. I think that might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried moving the count variable before the using statement, so that it is accessible outside the using as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes moving the view back worked thank you life save i also changed it like this as an example

```
ViewBag.Count = db.Bookings.SqlQuery(" SELECT * FROM dbo.Booking Where Gift_Aid = 'true' ").Count();
```